# How can I prevent autoplay in iframe HTML content?

Tags: html, iframe

I have used iframe with video autoplay stop. But it is always in autoplay mode. I do not want to autoplay. I want to stop autoplay.

My code is below:

```
 <iframe width="245" height="190" frameborder="0"
     src="Pacers_VS_Lakers_with_LifeWave_Energy_Patches.mp4?autoplay=0&cc_load_policy=1">
 </iframe>
```

Answer (score 10):

Just use the `video` tag instead of `iframe`:

```
<video height="100" width="100">
    <source src="some_video_url">
</video>
```

It will not autoplay itself. It's actually a better option instead of an iframe tag.

The `video` HTML tag has specific options, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Video#attributes

Answer (score 4):

Once, I had the same problem. I tried the following options:

- `<iframe width="245" height="190" src="filename.mp4?autoplay=0"></iframe>`
- `<iframe width="245" height="190" src="filename.mp4?autoplay=false"></iframe>`
- `<iframe width="245" height="190" src="filename.mp4?autostart=0"></iframe>`
- `<iframe width="245" height="190" src="filename.mp4?autostart=false"></iframe>`
- `<iframe width="245" height="190" src="filename.mp4?rel=0"></iframe>`
- `<iframe width="245" height="190" src="filename.mp4?rel=0&cc_load_policy=1"></iframe>`

But it never worked. **Using** the `<video>` **tag solved my issue:**

```
<video width="245" height="190" controls><source src="filename.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet may be to link a play button to the $("iframe").attr("src""abc.mp4") command and start your iframe with an img src instead.

I don't think autoplay can be turned off, at least with MP4 files.
So start with a static src and then use jQuery to change the src attribute to your video upon clicking a button/element; you can repeat this and have a bunch of different elements trigger their own videos.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the parameter `autoplay=false` instead of `autoplay=0`.

Comment: Here also same problem.

Comment: It's a raw mp4, not a YouTube HTML page.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried lots of methods, but none have worked for me.

Finally I found the reason.

I am using the

```
<iframe width="350" height="229.69" src="images/001.mp4"></iframe>
```

tag, and that's why autoplay is not stopping.

Use the `<video> </video>` tag. It will work. Add **"Control in video tag"**.

Comment: Why would you 'vandalize' an edit that makes your post readable?

Answer (score -3):

Add this:

```
autoplay=false
```

It should be solved.

Comment: It's a raw mp4, not a YouTube HTML page.

Answer (score -3):

Here you have to use the video tag to stop autoplay, but for responsive, use the `embed-responsive` class from [Bootstrap 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29):

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 hoverable">
  <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls>
    <source src="assets/Video/yourvideoname.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: "Here you have to use the video tag" — You are the fourth person to say that.

Comment: "but for responsive use the 'embed-resposive' class from Bootstrap4" — There are lots of ways to make it responsive, most don't depend on bootstrap, which the OP doesn't appear to be using.